# How to plot in Wireframe with CSV file - Numpy / Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I would like to plot in 3D with Pandas / MatplotLib / Numpy as a Wireframe

I'm using RFID sensors and I'm trying to record the signal I receive at different distance + different angles. And I want to see the correlation between the rising of the distance and the angle.

I've already a full CSV file which looks like this :

```
Distance;0      ;23    ;45     ;90
0       ;-33.24 ;-36.72;-39.335;-35.21
5       ;-31.73 ;-35.26;-41.56 ;-27.41
15      ;-31.175;-36.91;-40.74 ;-44.615
25      ;-35.305;-51.13;-45.515;-50.485
40      ;-35.205;-49.27;-55.565;-53.64
60      ;-41.8  ;-62.19;-58.14 ;-54.685
80      ;-47.79 ;-64.24;-58.285;-56.08
100     ;-48.43 ;-63.37;-64.595;-60.0
120     ;-49.07 ;-66.07;-63.475;-76.0
140     ;-50.405;-61.43;-62.635;-76.5
160     ;-52.805;-69.25;-71.0  ;-77.0
180     ;-59.697;-66.45;-70.1  ;nan
200     ;-56.515;-68.60;-73.4  ;nan
```

So that's why I want to plot in 3D :

- X Axis : Angle
- Y Axis : Distance
- Z Axis : signal (for each couple angle/distance)

On the first row we have the name of the index : `Distance`and the different angles : 0°, 23°, 45°, 90°

And on the first column we have the different distances which represent the Y axis.

And the matrix inside represents the signal, so, values of Z Axis...

I loaded my rawdata with Numpy :

```
raw_data = np.loadtxt('data/finalData.csv', delimiter=';', dtype=np.string_)
```

Then I used matplotlib to generate my wireframe :

```
angle    = raw_data[0 , 1:].astype(float)
distance = raw_data[1:, 0 ].astype(float)

data = ???? 

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

Z = data
X, Y = np.meshgrid(angle, distance)

ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z)

ax.set_xticks(angle)
ax.set_yticks(distance[::2])
ax.set_xlabel('angle')
ax.set_ylabel('distance')

plt.title('RSSI/angle/distance in wireframe')
plt.savefig('data/3d/3d.png')
plt.show()
```

But I don't know how to extract the signal for each couple angle/distance and put it in data.

I would like to know how to select the data to create the wireframe or to find another way to extract the data.

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I read the data in with pandas then grabbed the numpy arrays. Note the use of .values.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d

df= pd.read_csv('test.txt', sep=';')
df.index = df.Distance
del df['Distance']
raw_data = df

angle    = raw_data.columns.to_numpy().astype(float)
distance = raw_data.index.to_numpy().astype(float)

data = raw_data.to_numpy()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

Z = data
X, Y = np.meshgrid(angle, distance)

ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z)

ax.set_xticks(angle)
ax.set_yticks(distance[::2])
ax.set_xlabel('angle')
ax.set_ylabel('distance')

plt.title('RSSI/angle/distance in wireframe')
plt.savefig('data/3d/3d.png')
plt.show()
```

[image: Wireframe]

Edit Jan 2021: Pandas recommends user use `to_numpy()` instead of `values` now. see: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html

Comment: How do you read with pandas ? I used to read with Pandas like this : `df = pd.read_csv('data/finalData.csv',sep=';',index_col=0)`

Comment: Oops I left that out, that or something similar should work. I've edited the answer.